# How to allow utf-8 charset in preg_match?

Tags: php

I am using preg_match() function only to allow specific charachters to accept. It is allowing all alphabates and numbers but along with that i also want to allow utf-8 characters such as "ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ" so how can i allow this charachters from preg_match() function.Plase suggest me. Thanks in advance.

Regards

Shri

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the /u [pattern modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to let the PCRE engine know you're using UTF-8 patterns:

> This modifier turns on additional
>   functionality of PCRE that is
>   incompatible with Perl. Pattern
>   strings are treated as UTF-8. This
>   modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0
>   or greater on Unix and from PHP 4.2.3
>   on win32. UTF-8 validity of the
>   pattern is checked since PHP 4.3.5.