# Codeigniter Form Validation - Custom callback with regex that allows accents

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, preg-match

Before anyone flames me, I'd like to say I have tried all solutions here on SO as well as google but nothing works :(. I need some enlightenment :)

Here is my custom `form_validation` callback function.

**Code Snippet**

```
function _check_valid_text($text_string)
{
    if(empty($text_string)) return TRUE;
    if(!preg_match("/^[\pL\pN_ \w \-.,()\n]+$/i", $text_string))
    {
        // Set the error message:
        $this->form_validation->set_message('_check_valid_text', 'Invalid Character or symbol');
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

**WHAT I WANT:**

1. Allow all alphanumeric characters [a-z, A-Z & 0-9]
2. Allow accents
3. Allow the following too: space, open brace, close brace, dash, period and comma

**Strangely**

`für` works, i.e. no error (YAY!).
`trägen` does not :(

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

**PS:** Please don't provide solutions where your solution is to include the char that is not getting recognized into the `preg_match` string (e.g. add `ä` into the string). I am looking for a generic solution that works.

**PPS** I want to make a suggestion to the community. How about having a `library of regex expressions` for various cases? One can write a regex and once someone else verifies that it is working it can be accepted. Just a suggestion though. I assume there are more newcomers here like me who get stuck a lot in `regex-hell` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the *u* modifier to inform the regex engine that your string must be treated as an unicode string. Note too that you can reduce your character class, example:

```
$subjects = array('Wer nur den lieben Gott läßt walten',
                  'Sei gegrüßet Jesu gütig',
                  'Komm, Gott, Schöpfer, Heiliger Geist',
                  '←↑→↓');

$pattern = '~^[\pL\pN\s,.()_-]++$~u';

foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $subject, $match))
        echo '<br/>True';
    else
        echo '<br/>false';
}
```

Comment: Hi Casimir. Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately your solution also allows characters like `$`,`#`,`%`. I even tried to remove `\pP` but still it does not work :(. Love the German btw :)

Comment: @joshi: it is a copy/paste error, i will edit that. (Advice: try the code on the server, not with an online tool for this special case)

Comment: I am trying it on the server. Here is an example text. `Test String für trägen` which i want to pass through, and here is one where I want it to fail `Test String für trägen ^%^*`. Your `$pattern` is allowing both :(. To be more precise, I don't want any special chars to be allowed besides  space, open brace, close brace, dash, period and comma

Comment: @joshi: Sorry i have forgotten to put the anchors!

Comment: Sorry for this delayed reply. I had taken off from work yesterday. Now back to the topic: It Works!!!!! This is so awesome. I haven't tested it thoroughly upto now but I am pretty sure everything will work. Thank you so much Casimir! This has been so very helpful! Cheers! Joshi

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic solution to handle this because no predefined set of characters that meets your needs exists.

However, you can add the range of accented characters.

`[ ,-\.0-9A-Za-z\{\}À-ž]`

Also, see [How to allow utf-8 charset in preg_match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934135/how-to-allow-utf-8-charset-in-preg-match) for information on matching against a specific character set.

Comment: That would imply finding all possible ranges and creating a monster `preg_match()` sting :(. I am not liking it :(