# Extracting accented letters with preg_match

Tags: php, utf-8, preg-match, non-ascii-characters

Runnign this snippet of PHP code:

```
preg_match("/^sito in (.*) \(([A-Z]{2})\)(.*)( CAP )?([0-9]{5})?$/U", "sito in Paternò (CT) Contrada Palazzolo, 28 CAP 95047", $matches);
var_dump(trim($matches[1]));
```

leads to this result:

```
string(8) "Paternò�"
```

(yes, there is a garbage character after the accented letter)

instead of the expected:

```
string(7) "Paternò"
```

How I can correctly extract words containing accented letters using preg_match?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to allow utf-8 charset in preg\_match?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934135/how-to-allow-utf-8-charset-in-preg-match)

Comment: Are you sure it's not `trim()` or `var_dump()` that cause the issue ? Because your regex seems pretty correct to me. You could add the `u` modifier to treat everything as UTF-8 though ...

Comment: @Blackbam @tchap already tried the `u` modifier without success. Already tried without the `trim`. I'm pretty sure it isn't a display issue because I tried comparing the strings `($matches[1] == 'Paternò'` is false)

Comment: Did you try a lowercase /u ? Cause i think an uppercase /U means something different (http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Comment: Yes I tried /U /u and /uU. The uppercase U is correct because I'm also using a non-greedy matching. @Blackbam

Comment: try to add `(*UTF8)` at the start of your regex : `preg_match("/(*UTF8)^sito in (.*) \(([A-Z]{2})\)(.*)( CAP )?([0-9]{5})?$/U", "sito in Paternò (CT) Contrada Palazzolo, 28 CAP 95047", $matches);` see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9473867/1741150

Comment: @tchap already tried this too without success

Comment: Then the problem is somewhere else, since I cannot replicate on a standard PHP installation + your code. I get the expected result. PHP 5.3

Comment: @MarcoMarsala I don't think it's a problem with the code. If you're printing to a page, what's the encoding?... If it's command line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410424/command-line-character-encoding-from-phps-exec ... If on windows cmd: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650369/php-utf-8-to-windows-command-line-encoding  and check [iconv_set_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-set-encoding.php)

Comment: I'm on Windows command line. Already using the chcp 65001 trick. Tried iconv_set_encoding but no luck!